# Multi level dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am developing a jquery script to handle multiple clicks on dropdown elements.

The script add and remove a class based on a data attribute and remove it when clicked outside.

The problem is this:

If i nest another element with a class to toggle and I click on it, the parent element get it's class removed. I want the parent to keep it's class and apply the class the child needs.

How can I prevent this?

I have just one rule, **Absolutely no use of the e.stopPropagation().**

I have seen lot's of snippets and script with the stopPropagation method, and it's risky if I have other scripts interacting with the element.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```js
jQuery(function() {


  var toggled = [];

  jQuery('.js-toggle').each(function() {

    var el = jQuery(this),
      toToggle = el.attr('data-toggleClass');

    el.on('click', function(e) {

      if (el.hasClass(toToggle)) {

        el.removeClass(toToggle);
        el.removeClass('is-active');

        toggled.pop();

        

      } else {

        el.addClass(toToggle);
        el.addClass('is-active');

        if(toggled.indexOf(toToggle) === -1 ){

          toggled.push(toToggle);

        }

        

      }

    });

  });

  jQuery(document).on('click', function(e) {

    var targetEl = jQuery(e.target),
        
        toToggle = targetEl.attr('data-toggleClass'),
        
        lastToggled = toggled[toggled.length - 1],
        
        toggleType = jQuery('.js-toggle').attr('data-toggleType');

    if (!targetEl.is('.js-toggle') && !targetEl.is('.js-toggle *')) {

      switch (toggleType) {

          case 'all':

              jQuery('.js-toggle').each(function(){
                var el = jQuery(this),
                    elClass = jQuery(this).attr('data-toggleClass');

                el.removeClass(elClass);
                el.removeClass('is-active');

                toggled.pop();

                

              });

            break;

          case 'reverse':

            jQuery('.' + lastToggled).removeClass(lastToggled);

            toggled.pop();

            

            break;

        }

    }

  });

});
```

```css
      .box{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        display:inline-block;
        background: black;
        margin-right: 10px;
        position: relative;
      }
      .box .box{
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
      }
      .box.active{
        background: darkred;
      }
      .box.test-1{
        background: darkblue;
      }
      .box.test-2{
        background: darkgreen;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <div class="box js-toggle" data-toggleClass="active" data-toggleType="all">
        <div class="box js-toggle" data-toggleClass="test-1">

        </div>
      </div>

        <div class="box js-toggle" data-toggleClass="test-2">

        </div>

          <div class="box js-toggle" data-toggleClass="test-1">

          </div>
```

Comment: I would separate the methods and classes involving the child and the parent divs, and just have the clear function remove both

Answer (score 0):

You can use e.stopPropagation(); to prevent the event from bubbling up the DOM tree. You can also remove the .each() since .on() will already bind to all elements with the given class.

Example:

```
$('.js-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    toToggle = $(this).attr('data-toggleClass');
    if ($(this).hasClass(toToggle)) {
      $(this).removeClass(toToggle);
      $(this).removeClass('is-active');
      toggled.pop();
    } else {
      $(this).addClass(toToggle);
      $(this).addClass('is-active');

      if(toggled.indexOf(toToggle) === -1 ){
        toggled.push(toToggle);
      }
    }
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smulvihill/eptr2wbf/13/).